# Get only declared methods of a class in PHP

Tags: php, oop, cakephp

Hello I need to get only the methods declared in a class, and not the inherited methods. I need this for cakePHP. I am getting all the controllers, loading them and retrieving the methods from those controllers. But not only are the declared methods coming, but also the inherited ones.

Is there any method to get only declared methods.

Comment: I know no method except complicated reflection stuff. What do you need this for?

Comment: Can you let me know why you are doing this?  Is it for documentation or for use within the application?

Comment: I need to add all the public methods in controllers to my permissions table. I am using cakePHP's, and their ACL component isn't working with the existing model that I have.

Comment: @Joe- I need to add all the methods to a table in database. I am using cakePHP and their ACL component isn't fitting my existing model.

Comment: you can edit comments you know :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this (although a little more than "simple") with [`ReflectionClass`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php)

```
function getDeclaredMethods($className) {
    $reflector = new ReflectionClass($className);
    $methodNames = array();
    $lowerClassName = strtolower($className);
    foreach ($reflector->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC) as $method) {
        if (strtolower($method->class) == $lowerClassName) {
            $methodNames[] = $method->name;
        }
    }
    return $methodNames;
}
```

Comment: why are you using `ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC`?

Comment: It should be mentioned though, since it makes the answer incomplete to the question.

Answer (score 1):

From an architectural point of view, I think that reflection should be avoided if possible, but take a look at [ReflectionClass->getMethods()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php) if you think you know what you're doing.

```
<?php

class A {
    public function x() { }
    public function y() { }
}

class B extends A {
    public function a() { }
    public function b() { }
    public function x() { } // <-- defined here
}

$r = new ReflectionClass('B');
print_r($r->getMethods());

?>
```

You will get a list of methods defined by `B` and `A`, along with the class that last defined it. This is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ReflectionMethod Object
        (
            [name] => a
            [class] => B
        )

    [1] => ReflectionMethod Object
        (
            [name] => b
            [class] => B
        )

    [2] => ReflectionMethod Object
        (
            [name] => x
            [class] => B
        )

    [3] => ReflectionMethod Object
        (
            [name] => y
            [class] => A
        )

)
```

Comment: "From an architectural point of view, I think that reflection should be avoided if possible" why is that?

Comment: Hm, I guess it's personal preference. To me, reflection is similar to patching executables in-memory and *can* be unexpected (or expose such behavior) unless well-documented and can make your code more convoluted or introduce side-effects. However, it may prove useful for writing frameworks and meta-programming / extending a language's features.

Answer (score 0):

Came across a comment : "ReflectionClass::getMethods() sorts the methods by class (lowest in the inheritance tree first) then by the order they are defined in the class definition" here - http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php#115197

I verified this and it seems to be true. Based on the fact, we can add a little optimization to ircmaxell's solution to avoid iterating over other inherited methods. Also added some clean up to avoid constructor\destructor:

```
public function getMethods($className) 
{   
    $methodNames = [];
    $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass(className); 
    $publicMethods = $reflectionClass->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
    $lowerClassName = strtolower($className);
    foreach ($publicMethods as $method) {
        if (strtolower($method->class) == $lowerClassName) {
            // You can skip this check if you need constructor\destructor  
            if (!($method->isConstructor() ||
                $method->isDestructor())) {
                $methodNames[] = $method->getName();
            }
        } else {
            // exit loop if class mismatch
            break;
        }
    }
    return $methodNames;
}
```