# Scan PHP class methods

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get only declared methods of a class in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712671/get-only-declared-methods-of-a-class-in-php)

Is there any way to "scan" all the methods in class and get them returned as strings in array?

Let's say i have this:

```
class House {

   public function doors(){
      // Doors code
   }

   public function windows()
   {
      // Windows code
   }

}
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
$methods = ['doors','windows'];
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: [`get_class_methods()`](http://php.net/get_class_methods)

Comment: Will that also work on objects? thanks

Comment: @user1141356 At least try to read a manual...

Comment: found it, sorry for any inconvenience and thanks for answers.

Comment: @Lukas1, maybe you should also read the manual.

Comment: @smott heh sorry :-D  my bad

Comment: @user1141356 `get_class_methods(get_class($object));`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is called reflection. Use [PHP Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php)