# Get available methods from class without extends

Tags: php, class, oop, extend

Is is possible to get all methods from one class and filter out methods that are available because of `extends`?
Example:

```
class core{
   public function1(){}
}
class extender extends core{
   public function2(){}
   public function3(){}
}
```

When I call `get_class_methods()` on `extender`, it returns this:

- function1
- function2
- function3

I only want to see:

- function2
- function3

How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you tried to make it private?

Comment: Yes, that works but the method should not be private so it's no solution for this case.

Comment: I pick one that should help you: [ReflectionClass](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3712754/2097224)

Comment: Ah, yes that helped me! Thank you!